# I tried to do web scraping with python and the output is empty. did i do something wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is the code that i used, you can see that i copied the result page and tried to print it and the output is [ ]. I'm trying to learn web-scraping. so, i'm trying to web-scrape the name of the orphanage and copy inta csv file. but, i couldn't get the first phase. The "result_page" exists.

```
import os
os.system('cls')

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Orphanages/nct-10344906')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
MainContent = soup.find_all(class_="result_page")
print(MainContent)
```

Comment: Does the class ```class_="result_page"``` exist?

Comment: What do you wanna scrape from this page?

Comment: have you meet 10054 error?

Comment: i haven't gotten error the output in the console is [ ].

Comment: what `print(soup)` is giving?

Comment: **empty list [ ]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this error even though the page has result_page at the root, it indicates that the page has been blocked

**[UPDATE1]**

I tried this for about access or not :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Orphanages/nct-10344906')
soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

and output:

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Orphanages/nct-10344906" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.95a0de52.1603091762.1ae82063
</p></body>
</html>
```

**[UPDATE2]**

finally unblocked

code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Orphanages/nct-10344906',headers=headers).text
soup = bs(r,'html.parser')
soup = soup.find("div",{"class":"result_page"})
print(soup)
```

**NOT:** If you still get errors, make sure you are using the correct user-agent.
go to google site press to F12 and Network, refresh the page and press a thing

[image]

Comment: is it blocked from any web-scraping or is it not available general public ?

Comment: some site do not response to the request which dnose not has User-Agent, that's why it doesn't work. I'ma see how to add user-agent

Comment: i tried after seeing your update. I'm still getting the empty list [ ] not the "access denied". is it somekind regional access ?

Comment: I do not think so, I am using different user-agents now, but I still keep getting errors. I will try until I find the right thing, I will inform you

Comment: I think i found the issue. while reading the websites policies. It is stated that the data mining and web-scrapping is not allowed. thank you for your effort

Comment: There's a way around it and the answer is above, check out my answer

Comment: Thank you dude. Much appreciated 

Comment: If your question is answered, don't forget to answer it correctly, good luck :)